# How can I handle virtual subdirectories with regex in app.yaml?

Tags: regex, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I'd like to point all of my visitors to "single subdirectories" to one page, and all visitors to "double subdirectories" to another. E.g:

```
/foo/
/new/
/north/
/1-j4/
```

Would all point to 1.app, whereas

```
/foo/bar/
/new/york/
/north/west/
/1-j4/a_990/
```

Would all point to 2.app.

I figured I could do this with non-greedy regex matching, like so:

```
- url: /(.*?)/$
  script: 1.app

- url: /(.*?)/(.*?)/$
  script: 2.app
```

To my confusion, both /foo/ and /foo/bar/ resolve to script 1.app. Does the "lazy" regex force itself up to include the middle /, since that's the only way to get a match? How else can I do this? I have tried using (\w*?) but get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*?` will still match through any amount of `/` because `.` matches any character but a line break char (by default). You need to base your regexps on a negated character class, `[^/]*`, that matches 0 or more chars other than `/`.

To match directories with one part, use `^([^/]*)/?$` and to match those with 2, use `^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$`.

Note that if you plan to use the patterns in online Web testers, you will have to escape `/` in most of them as by default they use `/` symbol as a regex delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `(.*?)` includes slashes, so will resolve to `1.app`.  If you put the `2.app` handler first, it should do what you want:

```
- url: /(.*?)/(.*?)/$
  script: 2.app

- url: /(.*?)/$
  script: 1.app
```